# Ponyfill for CSS variables won't work properly: css-vars-ponyfill

Tags: javascript, css

I have defined some css variables inside of `:root`. To have them work with IE I need some Polyfill: https://jhildenbiddle.github.io/css-vars-ponyfill/#/

Somehow I can't make it work. That's what I got so far:

```
import cssVars from 'css-vars-ponyfill';

cssVars({
    include: "style",
    onlyLegacy: true
});
```

It works when I add `variables: {}` and insert all of the variables I used within CSS - but is there some way that I don't have to add all variables manually and it automatically takes them from `:root`?

Comment: you need to post a stylesheet and eventually the html to find out if you include correctly the css where stands your css(--var), your example only look at your style inside the <style> tag of your html document, not te one linked via link. have you tried something alike : `include       : 'link[rel=stylesheet],style',` like said in the doc ? to parse both <style> and css file ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I'm using reactjs and my `:root` including all the vars are located inside of `index.css`

Comment: did you linked index.css to the polyfill ?  do you have a sanbox online or so ?